# Tomcat webapp deployment in docker image fails only on linux machines

Tags: java, linux, docker, tomcat

I have a simple tomcat based docker image which builds and runs without any problems on Mac and Windows machines but fails on Linux Machines when the .war file is deployed.

The docker image:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-jre11-openjdk-slim

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx10G -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED"

COPY webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

The corresponding docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services: 
    webapp:
        container_name: mytool
        build: webapp
        ports: 
            - "8080:8080"
```

The webapp.war is recommended to be used with tomcat 8 and jre 11.

The severe error in logs:

```
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.71
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 9 2021 18:43:14 UTC
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.71.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.4.109+
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/local/openjdk-11
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.12+7
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx10G
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.31] using APR version [1.7.0].
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [{4}].
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1523 ms
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/8.5.71]
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/webapp.war]
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Oct 05 11:45:02 UTC 2021]; root of context hierarchy
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web-application-config.xml]
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webmvc-config.xml]
```

```
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext 
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name '...': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field '...'; 
...
doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
```

and this only occurs on Linux machines (tested with debian and ubuntu).
Any hints?

Comment: You should add the whole error message to your question. This seems to be a JAXB problem (which was removed in Java 11). Are you sure you are not using Java 8 on Mac and Windows?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I've updated the logs to show that the docker image is build with tomcat 8.5 and a JVM Version 11. And how could the version be different on different machines if it is declared in the docker file with *tomcat:8.5-jre11-openjdk-slim*?